# remove 'PerformanceWarning' message while looping through multiple dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, performance, loops, deprecation-warning

I would like to reset index for multiple dataframe, I create a list of container then loop through each one dataframe but I got 'PerformanceWarning'. Should I ignore it or any other way to remove the warning signs ?

```
df_list = [short_frml,mid_frml,long_frml]

for x in df_list:
    x.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
x.reset_index(inplace=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your error is not directly due to `reset_index` but rather to something you did before.

The best might be to solve this in the beginning. How did you construct those dataframes?

That said, an easy option to fix it would be to make a copy, which `reset_index` is doing:

```
for i in range(len(df_list)): 
    df_list[i] = df_list[i].reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks mozway, your answer is very helpful